# Suddenly seeing "no wifi adapter found"

Tags: wireless

I have a system running Ubuntu 18.04, and it has been connecting to wifi just fine for months.  Since this morning, there is no wifi connection, and when I go in the wifi settings I see the message "No wifi adapter found".  Nothing has changed, and this was working just fine as of yestrday.

I do dual-boot the system to Windows, and I was using Windows yesterday - this is the only variable I can think of where something might have changed.

How can I go about debugging this issue?

edit: wifi *does* still work in Windows, and a Windows update did run yesterday, I'm not sure if this could be related

Answer (score 4):

It turns out the problem was Windows.

There's a setting for: "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" in the device manager which seems to have been disabling the wifi adapter.  This option has to be disabled.

The option can be found here:

Device Manager -> Network Adapters -> <network adapter> -> Power Management

I would still like to know how to turn on the network adapter in Ubuntu directly.

Comment: Thanks! Same thing happened to me.

Comment: It is amazing what windows allows itself to do.

Answer (score 1):

Q: I would still like to know how to turn on the network adapter in Ubuntu directly.

A: Then you need to modprobe the module. To find your module, when connected, type in a terminal

```
nmcli
```

For example mine is a Broadcom network adapter and the module is brcmfmac. To turn it on I would type

```
sudo modprobe brcmfmac
```

So once you figure yours out give it a try and let us know.